# Magnetic quadrupole and dipole

Tags: magnetic-fields

We can create a quadrupole magnetic field disposing magnetic dipole as in this figure
[image]
I have two question about this:

1. How can I write the quadrupole moment in terms of the dipole?;
2. Is it correct to say that a product of four dipole moments is a quadrupole?